# Material UI and React How to create a branch line for the sub menu?

Tags: material-ui

[image: [Sample Image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeUg6.jpg)]

Hello, I'm new to MUI and React and wanted to see if is there a way to get this "branch line" for the sub menu?
I attached photo for reference where the Settings have a branch lines into the child sub menu

Thank you!!